# Why does requestIdleCallback give me more than 16 ms of time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I thought that our code gets about 16ms of time to execute, since the rendering rate is 60 fps, so 1000 /60 = ~16ms. However, if I run this in Chrome:

```
requestIdleCallback((deadline)=>{
    console.log(deadline.timeRemaining(), deadline.didTimeout)
});
```

`timeRemaining` gives me `49.9ms` of time. Does it mean that Chrome doesn't re-render every 16ms? I assume that it's true in this case, if nothing changes there's no need to re-render.

Comment: I'm curious: Are you still getting this behavior with a recent version of Chrome? I used to only get one callback with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLw2815t/3/) (see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059977/why-does-requestidlecallback-give-me-more-than-16-ms-of-time/53060101?noredirect=1#comment93019660_53060101)), but now I get repeated ones, and the deadlines I get are consistent with my refresh rate. But another user seems to still get 50ms from your code (though not from that fiddle).

Comment: haven't looked at this for a long time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spec supports your assumption. In [Start an idle period algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/requestidlecallback/#dfn-start-an-idle-period-algorithm) it says:

> 7. Let *deadline* be a time in the future until which the browser expects to remain idle. The user agent should choose *deadline* to ensure that no time-critical tasks will be delayed even if a callback runs for the whole time period from now to *deadline*. As such, **it should be set to the minimum of**: the closest timeout in the list of active timers as set via setTimeout and setInterval; the scheduled runtime for pending animation callbacks posted via requestAnimationFrame; **pending internal timeouts such as deadlines to start rendering the next frame**, process audio or any other internal task the user agent deems important.

*(my emphasis)*

So if there were an internal pending timeout to render the next frame, the deadline would have to be before then.

Comment: @MaxWizardK - :-) No worries, I should say that this is a relatively new one on me, and I'm slightly confused by its behavior on Chrome without a timeout if the callback doesn't change the DOM, so...

Comment: I'm reverse-engineering Fiber algorithm now, so getting deep into this new scheduling stuff. Can you elaborate on "without a timeout if the callback doesn't change the DOM" in your comment?

Comment: @MaxWizardK - I find the behavior of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLw2815t/3/) odd on Chrome: I get only one callback. But I need to study the API more (which sadly I don't have time for today); with your greater knowledge of the API, it'll probably make sense to you on first glance.  :-)

Comment: I just googled here. May I ask why in the above fiddle the remaining time is always about 16.6ms (which reflects the 60Hz refresh rate) but if I directly run Max's code, it's 50ms? What is the factor that decides the remaining time of a rIC callback?

Comment: @AGamePlayer - Sadly, I don't know. I fairly consistently get values around 9.5ms (with dips sometimes down to 8.9 or so), which is a reasonable number for my 100MHz refresh rate where nominally the screen repaints every 10ms. That's if I run that fiddle or run Max's code directly.

Comment: [The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLw2815t/3/) I mention [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059977/why-does-requestidlecallback-give-me-more-than-16-ms-of-time/53060101?noredirect=1#comment93019660_53060101) gives me repeated callbacks now, so I'm guessing it was a Chrome bug (as the fiddle hasn't changed).